# Collaboratively annotate an image

Tags: images, maps, collaboration, annotation

I'm looking for a service that would allow me to upload a large map and allow several people to mark certain locations on it. Would be nice if I could categorize the markers and only view certain categories at once, and export the marker coordinates into a CSV or something similar.

Edit: I looked into a few services, right now I'm going with Google Earth Pro and have imported my map image and roughly overlaid it with the real world location.

Comment: Do you mean an image or a map?  Do you want to be able to put markers on Google Maps, or put markers on an arbitrary image file?

Comment: I meant both, in a sense. I have an image of a map I want people to be able to put icons indicating things like signs or lights.

Comment: Yeah, Google Earth would be a good choice